# What is the modern way to do Angular content projection?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

I've found a lot of old ways to transclude/content project, and I followed the latest method (I assume) found here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

I'm trying to include another components html file inside of a modal in another component. They are sibling components, not parent/child, which is why I think its not working.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Dialog html:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>
    Title here
</h1>

<div mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
    Actions here
</div>
```

Dialog component:

```
import {Component, OnInit}                   from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog,
    MatDialogRef,
    MAT_DIALOG_DATA}                     from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector    : 'test-dialog',
    templateUrl : 'test-dialog.html',
    styleUrls   : ['./test-dialog.scss']
})
export class Test implements OnInit
{
    constructor(public  dialog: MatDialog) {}

    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

test.html, What I want to include:

```
<test-dialog>
    I want to include this content
</test-dialog>
```

test component:

```
import {Component, OnInit}      from '@angular/core';
import {Router}                 from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector    : 'test-component',
    templateUrl : './test.html'
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit
{

    constructor(public router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

EDIT: I also already included `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` inside the module of what I want to include

Comment: And what is the markup of `test` component?

Comment: @Antoniossss It's a very long legal HTML file :)

Comment: So what, its related to problem. What you have shown in `dialog` should be your test markup

Comment: Take a look into Angular Elements https://angular.io/guide/elements - they might be useful to you.

Comment: @Antoniossss, to answer your question - yes I do believe there is a difference between using `ng-content` by itself rather than using the framework Angular supplied for custom elements. Do you not? I recognize there is some overlap, but I wouldn't say they are the same thing.

Comment: @marshalllegend It looks like Angular Elements is a v6 release and we're using v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this with a help from a friend.

I simply included the selector in the HTML as you would do if you were placing a component:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <test-component>
    </test-component>
</div>
```

The difference being because it is a sibling component, you have to import the module. If you import the component, Angular will complain about you importing it twice (once in the dialog module and once in the test module).

```
import {TestModule}       from '../test/test.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TermsOfServiceModule
    ],
```

And in test.module you have to export the component

```
exports: [
    TestComponent
],
```

Slightly tricky nuance that I hope will help someone else in the future.